# Transfer multiple point to polyline based on spatial location

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, line

I have a number of polylines (bus routes) and points (bus stops). The polylines span from stop to stop. Each stop has an ID, a single number.

I am trying to get the point ID that touches each polyline into the polyline so each polyine will have stop 1 and stop 2 which it spans between.

Any thoughts on how I can do this?

I have tried a spatial join which will give me two polylines, one for each stop it intersects.

Comment: You're joining the wrong way around, find the *line* that's closest to each *point* i.e. join the points to the lines.. this could be problematic if a 'stop' exists on more than one 'line', do you have an advanced license? If so try Generate Near Table and attribute join the near table to the lines and calculate joining to the existing values.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the Stop ID's concatenated in a single field for each Polyline, Spatial Join will work. In the Field Map, select a field,Merge,Join. Define the delimiter such as Comma. This will produce something like "1,2,3,4"